# Jape file for Basic phone number Detection GATE NLP

Tags: nlp, gate

I am new to GATE NLP. I started learning and going through GATE tutorials to understand the basics. I Tried some text formats in GATE Developer tool.

Steps I followed

1. I download GATE Developer tool from this site. https://gate.ac.uk/download/
2. Navigated to downloaded folder.
3. Ran the command ./gate.sh
4. Went through some You tube videos to understood the basics.
5. Loaded Annie Application
6. Removed Annie orthomatcher and Annie NE Transducer
7. Added New GATE Document
8. Created a new corpus with the document
9. On Processing Resource added new JAPE Transducer, Mapped a sample JAPE File

I wanted to add some new rules in jape files to detect the given phone number formats from word documents.
Format1: `+14168878659`, Format2: `+1-4036187846`, Format3: `+1.647.400.3581`, Format4 : `+1 647 400 3581`

I wrote Jape File  for processing `+14168878659`

```
Phase:Address
Input:  Token Lookup
Options: control = appelt
            
Macro: PHONE_COUNTRYCODE1
 ({Token.string == "+1"}
     {Token.kind == number,Token.length == "2"} |
     {Token.kind == number,Token.length == "11"} 
  )
            
  Rule:PhoneReg1
  Priority: 20
            
  (
   (PHONE_COUNTRYCODE1)
  ):phoneNumber1 -->:phoneNumber1.Phone = {kind = "phoneNumber1", rule = "PhoneReg1"}
```

Can someone tell me how to write jape for these formats? `+1-4036187846`,`+1.647.400.3581`, `+1 647 400 3581`
I know these may be not valid formats. I am doing this for learning purpose.